# Django - Aggregating scores based on nested objects

Tags: django, django-views, nested, aggregate

my model is structured as follows:

- Model A -> Bundle

  - Model B -> Products

    - Model C -> Products Feedback

Example:

- Bundle X

  - Product A

    - Feedback #A.1: score = 4
    - Feedback #A.2: score = 5
  - Product B

    - Feedback #B.1: score = 2
    - Feedback #B.2: score = 4
      ...

In the "Bundle" detail view, I'd like to show this:

- Bundle X

  - Product A (avg score = 4.5)
  - Product B (avg score = 3.0)

While in the "Product" details view I'm able to display the average scores, in the "Bundle" details view I'm able to display the list of products related to it, but I can't figure out how to show the scores.

Any idea?

Here some relevant code:

```py
class BundleDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Bundle 
    template_name = 'bundle_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context =  super(BundleDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        bundle = self.object
        context["hyp"] = Product.objects.filter(bundle=bundle).order_by('bundle')

        return context
```

```py
class ProductDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Product 
    template_name = 'product_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context =  super(ProductDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        test_conducted = self.object
        context["test_conducted"] = ProductFeedback.objects.filter(product_tested=test_conducted).order_by('test_conducted')
        a_s = ProductFeedback.objects.filter(product_tested=test_conducted).all().aggregate(Avg('score'))
        h_t = ProductFeedback.objects.filter(product_tested=test_conducted).all().aggregate(Count('score'))
        context["avg_score"] = round(a_s['score__avg'],1)
        context["nr_tests"] = h_t['score__count']

        return context
```

bundle_details:

```html
...

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
        {% for a in hyp %}
        <div class="card mb-2 mt-2 left top">
            <div class="card-body">                
                <div> 
                    <b> 
                        <a href="{% url 'product_detail' a.pk  %}" class="card-title text-muted">{{ a.product }} </a>
                    </b>
                </div>
                
                       ...

            </div>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a method to the Product class, something like this:-

```
def avg_score(self):
  a_s = ProductFeedback.objects.filter(product_tested=self).all().aggregate(Avg('score'))
  return round(a_s['score__avg'],1)
```

Then in the template you can get the average score simply by writing:-

```
{{ product.avg_score }}
```